# How can I get more details of attachment using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a small Google Script to extract the details of my emails especially the attachments. In this example I am trying to get the 'user' and 'attachment' details in the Log window.

After running the code, I can see the 'attachment details' as :-
1) GmailAttachment - wherever attachment is present
2) Undefined - wherever attachment isn't present

I would like to check that how can I get more details of Attachment like Name of Attachment, Url of Attachment, type etc. is that possible through Google Scripting?

```
function testing1() {
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
   var mail1 = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
   for(var x=0;x<mail1.length;x++){
    var msg = mail1[x].getMessages();
     for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
       var mesg = msg[i].getBody();
       var att = msg[i].getAttachments()[0];
       Logger.log(att);
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your guidance.
Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through attachments (if available) and get the file name and size from the [GmailAttachment class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment).

```
 for(var i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
   var mesg = msg[i].getBody();
   var att = msg[i].getAttachments();
   for (var a=0; a<att.length; a++) {
     Logger.log(att[1].getName());
     Logger.log(att[1].getSize());
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for your help, It is very useful.
But I couldn't get an option to get 'URL of the Attachment' (so if I click on that the link respective Attachment will open) in this "GmailAttachment class" section. Is this option not available in Google Apps Script?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment has all of the methods you can perform on the attachment. There is one variable for checking if it is a google attachment (and hence would have a url), I'd cycle through all the methods with one attachment and see if any of them happen to contain what you want.